# How do I deploy wars to JBossWeb using context files, like in Tomcat

Tags: jboss, tomcat6

In Tomcat 6, I can create context fragment files in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost` to handle the deployment of wars (instead of copying the war to the webapps folder).

Is it possible to do the same thing with the instance of Tomcat that's embedded in JBoss 5.1.0 (JbossWeb)?

If so, where do I put the context file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such possibility, but you can set up JBoss to install application from other directories that `deploy`.

In your profile you have to find these file `conf/bootstrap/profile.xml` and there you can find something like that:

```
<property name="applicationURIs">
    <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
        <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

You can add extra line with the new directory to scan:

```
<property name="applicationURIs">
    <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
        <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>

        <!-- Nowy katalog do skanowania -->
        <value>file:///nfs/applications</value>
    </list>
</property>
```